# Is the following endgame position a draw or white has advantage?

Tags: endgame, bishop-endgame

[image]

Hello, this is my first question on this site. Is the above position a draw or an advantage for white? I checked a few engines at different depths, some say it is advantage for white , some say it is draw.

The general strategy I guess for white would be to play Kf4 and try to win the g pawn. Black's king is temporarily unable to come to the 7th rank due to the white pawn and bishop combine. But can white win the g-pawn without letting go of his own pawn ?

Thanks.

Comment: Tablebase app here http://www.k4it.de/?topic=egtb&lang=en says it is a draw.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This endgame is a clear draw.

Black simply has to maintain his king on f8 and keep the bishop alive and White cannot make progress.

The only way White can win this position is if he can either capture Black's bishop and promote the f-pawn or simply promote his f-pawn. Capturing the g-pawn is not enough to win. If Black plays correctly, the Black bishop will never be captured, and as long as he maintains the king on f8, there is no way for White to drive out the king from f8 (no way to give check) and promote the f-pawn. So it is a draw.

I have attached here below the result from the endgame tablebases which have already evaluated this position. As you can see, all moves from White lead to a draw at best play. You can yourself enter this position and play with the tablebase on [this](http://www.k4it.de/?topic=egtb&lang=en) website.

[image]

Comment: I was unaware of tablebase sites. Will use them in the future. To be sure, tablebases are available when there are 6 or less pieces right ?

Comment: There are some 7 piece tablebases, see http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/351/what-is-the-status-for-seven-man-end-game-table-bases/353#353 . But mostly 6, yeah. The 7 man are 140TB in total size or so.