# Is there a spreadsheet of all 5 or fewer men endgame tablebase continuations/results? How could one be made?

Tags: endgame, database, tablebases

I am looking for a spreadsheet such as the one here: https://data.world/uci/chess-king-rook-vs-king, except that it covers all 5 or less men endgames. Ideally it would also have PGNs of the ideal continuation and/or FENs for each position.

Does that exist? How could I go about making one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a freely available online 7 piece Endgame tablebase?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/5253/is-there-a-freely-available-online-7-piece-endgame-tablebase)

Comment: Edited for bad grammar

Comment: Is the word "spreadsheet" essential in your question, or did you use this "innocently" (maybe not knowing common file formats for endgame table bases)? In the link you gave the data is indeed in an excel (or similar) spreadsheet, but this is a very unusual because inefficient formait for tablebases. I don't think it is suitable for "all 5 or fewer men" tablebases, and I doubt you can find this anywhere. Most answers point you to places where you can find syzygy tables, IDK whether this is relevant for you or not.

Comment: The Nalimov tablebases, which use advanced compression techniques, require 7.05 GB of storage space for all 5-piece endings, 30 MB for the 4-piece endings, and 
 62 kB for 3-pieces. (These are just KRK, KQK and KPK, unless I'm wrong.) Now the size of the KRK **spreadsheet** (~500KB as CSV)  should correspond to a fraction of the 3-piece tablebase, say 15k. So the **spreadsheet** tablebase for 5 pieces would use at least 30 x 7 GB = 210 GB (as CSV). I think you can't use such a spreadsheet with EXCEL or similar (it takes up even much more space in memory than as CSV file on the disk).

Answer (score 2):

If you search "tablebase chess" on google, this link should be the first result:
https://syzygy-tables.info/

Once there, scroll down to the table with the columns "Host, "Info", "List". These should give you access to all the possible endgames with seven or fewer pieces. Note that the files for each endgame aren't human readable though. I'm not sure if you program, but if you do there should be ways to work with the files. E.g., see:
https://github.com/official-stockfish/Stockfish/blob/master/src/syzygy/tbprobe.cpp
for how Stockfish accesses the tablebases in C++. You could start at the probe_dtz function.

Note that the combined file sizes of all the tablebases is a number of terabytes, but if you're only interested in 5 or fewer pieces, this should be exponentially lower (easily stored on a modern computer I'd imagine).

Comment: > I'm not sure if you program, but if you do there should be ways to work with the files. E.g., see: https://github.com/official-stockfish/Stockfish/blob/master/src/syzygy/tbprobe.cpp for how Stockfish accesses the tablebases in C++. You could start at the probe_dtz function.

I'm not a programmer, my total programming background is the equivalent of 2 high school courses I took. Still, I think I will try that or find someone else to help if I can't do it.